# Quit within 3 months of Joining

Tags: resignation, transition

I worked for an MNC till about 3 months back. I was offered a position in a local company with a higher position / marginally higher salary and was recruited for a high profile Project. I joined this company specifically because of the project. I made that clear while joining also.

However, 3 months have passed and I don't see the project starting anytime soon. I am informed that it will take another 6 - 12 months before the project could start.

If I remove the project from the whole engagement, there is nothing to work for. The work culture is shit. My department is full of negativity and internal politics.

The department does have many routine things going on. But I dont want to get involved into that. These activities ('projects' as some call it) - I have done these 7-8 years back. I have been in leadership position past 4-5 years - so I even had my juniors do such 'projects' under my mentor-ship. I am looking for stuff that will give me some value-addition / learning opportunities as well.

My questions:

1) I have decided to quit - once i get a good opportunity elsewhere. May be next 3 months but not more. Whether there is anything else i can do?

2) How do i manage this in the conversation with the next recruiter? For 10 years of career, current local company would be 6th one (2 of them closed down or terminated lot of people around the time i quit. For the rest my average working tenure is 2.5 - 3 years.). This is worrying me too much. How do i manage this in the conversation with the company?

2a) When Do i tell them at that I am working for this company for very short term, and elaborate the problem? Do i tell the recruiter? or do i tell only to the company?

3) Looking at my employment history, I am thinking I am no longer fit for staying an "employee". I want to transition to entrepreneur / start my own business. Sheer shittiness of corporate world makes me dizzy. I do have some money which will help me stay afloat for 2 years without any income (incl. mortgage payments).

Comment: Ignore mentioning this in your CV. No questions asked. If potential employeer will find out you can tell that the probation time was over and you decised that the company nad job wasn't a good fit.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see this as too much of an issue given your past experience and tenure. You have learnt a valuble lesson though - don't join a company just because you like the sound of one project! **Projects can change.** Concentrate on finding a job that you like a range of work and the *type* of projects they do.

> 1) Whether there is anything else i can do?

**- You sound like you've made up your mind, but have you tried seeing if there are any other interesting projects?**

> 2) How do i manage this in the conversation with the next recruiter/company?

**- You tried it for 3 months and decided it wasn't for you, just tell them the company wasn't a good fit. As I said, given your tenure at previous places it shouldn't be an issue**

> 2a) When Do i tell them at that I am working for this company for very short term, and elaborate the problem? Do i tell the recruiter? or do i tell only to the company?

**- Don't, just let them bring it up if they have an issue. They will see it on your CV anyway**

Number 3 didn't seem to contain a question but if you want to become an entrepreneur I would say go for it and good luck! (Note that's my opinion only)

Comment: Good advice, which would be clearer if you used the 'blockquote' function or greater-than sign to indicate the parts of the question that you are quoting. Would you like me to edit it for you?